# Calling a view from a management command

Tags: python, django, httprequest

So I have added a command to manage.py in my django app that basically takes the results from a view and emails them out to specific users.  This command will run on a cron schedule - basically this is done as an automated, emailed report.

I've figured out how to add in the command but I want to call the view now.  The problem is that I have no HttpRequest object and whenever I read the django docs on HttpRequest, my eyes glaze over and I struggle to follow it.  I'm not sure exactly how to create an HttpRequest object that will satisfy my needs nor if there's another way to get this done.  I also tried passing 'None' in as the request object but that didn't lead anywhere.

Help?

Comment: It would be non-trivial to build `HttpRequest`. Rather separate out your code into another function that does not depend upon `request` and call it from command as well as view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your situation is as follows:

```
def superDuperView(request, params,...): 
   # The logic lies here which is intended to be reused.
   ......
   ......
   return HttpResponse('template.html', {somedata})
```

You would like to reuse your view's logic in a management command. But calling a view is without request response lifecycle seems not to be possible. Thus segregation of logic and your view would help you:

```
def superDuberBusinessLogic(user, params,...): 
   #implement your logic here without a need of any request.
   ......
   return result
```

The you view would become:

```
def superDuperView(request, params,...): 
   # You could pass user your logic if you need.
   data = superDuberBusinessLogic(request.user, params,....)
   return HttpResponse('template.html', {data})
```

You could use your `superDuberBusinessLogic` in your management command.

Answer (score 3):

I'll fully admit to the hacky nature of this but if it works is it stupid?

```
from django.test import Client

user = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)[0]
assert user.is_authenticated()

c = Client()
c.force_login(user)

resp = c.get( reverse('frontend:csv-view', kwargs={'company':company.name}) )
print resp.content
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is in the situation where they need a `request` object,
a simple solution might be to use the `curl` command from a `cron` job

This is useful for eg. to build an absolute url in an email template

eg.

```
30 08 10 06 * curl http://localhost/your/view/param/etc/etc/
```

This bypasses the need for any management command codes.